# Array showing only first result good

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write this code on few ways, but always the result is good only for first team all other results are bad.
When I put id of some other club instead of $id I get the good result for that team but than is only one row, I want to show all 20 teams.

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Played</th><th>0,5</th><th>1,5</th><th>2,5</th>
<th>3,5</th><th>4,5</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$teams = mysql_query("select * from teams");
$num_teams = mysql_num_rows($teams);

while ($group = mysql_fetch_row($teams)) {
   $id_team[] = $group; 
 }

for ($a = 0; $a < $num_teams; $a++) {

if (isset($num_array)) {
mysql_data_seek($query_array, 0 );
$search_array_over = array();
}

$id = $id_team[$a][0];
$name_over = $id_team[$a][1];

 $query_array = mysql_query("select * from full_stat where kl1 = $id or kl2 = $id");
 $num_array = mysql_num_rows($query_array);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_array)) {
$data_over[] = $row;    
 }


 $search_array_over = array('1' => '0', '2' => '0' ,'3' => '0', '4' => '0','5' => '0','6' => '0');
 for ($now = 0;$now < $num_array; $now++) {
    $over_pass = ($data_over[$now][3] + $data_over[$now][4]);

    for ($pass = 1; $pass < 7; $pass++) {
        if ($over_pass >= $pass)     {
            $final_pass = $pass;
        }
        else {
            $final_pass = '6';
        }

if (array_key_exists($final_pass, $search_array_over)) {
    $search_array_over[$final_pass] += 1;
        }
else {
    $search_array_over[$final_pass] = 1;

 }
 }
 }


 echo '<tr><td>'.$name_over.'</td><td>'.$num_array.'</td>     <td>'.$search_array_over[1].'</td><td>'.$search_array_over[2].'</td><td>'.$search_array_over[3].'</td><td>'.$search_array_over[4].'</td><td>'.$search_array_over[5].'</td></tr>';
 }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is one confusing block of PHP code.

A better explanation of your final output would probably help here, but I'm going to guess it's the teamlist plus their statistics.

Since dissecting your current code strikes me as painful, I'm going to describe how I would do this instead.

In your database you have 2 tables, "team" and "team_stats"

Team Structure:

```
id int
name varchar
....
```

Stats Structure:

```
team_id int
someStat int
otherStat int
....

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM team LEFT JOIN team_stats ON team_stats.team_id");
$stmt -> execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetch_all();
foreach($result as $team) {
     // output data to page
}
```

?>